# How to write proper loop in [C]

Tags: c

I need to make 10 numbers display using "loops" like this:

```
1 
2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10
```

I managed to make it happen with the code below. But I feel like there must be an easier way to do this. What if I needed to do the same pattern, but had 1000 numbers? That would be a lot of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x;
    x=1;

    do {
        printf("%i \n", x);
        x++;
    }   while (x<=1);

        do {
            printf("%i ", x);
            x++;

    }   while (x<=3); {
        printf("\n");
    }

    do {
        printf("%i ", x);
        x++;

    }   while (x<=6); {
        printf("\n");
    }
    do {
        printf("%i ", x);
        x++;

    }   while (x<=10); {
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int row = 1;
    int column = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);

        if (column == row) {
            printf("\n");
            row++;
            column = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
            column++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Writing a separate loop for each row is insane. When you're doing the same thing over and over with slight variation, that means you need another wrapping loop. This should really only require a pair of `for` loops:

```
unsigned maxval = ...;
for (unsigned rowlen = 1, val = 1; val <= maxval; ++rowlen) {
    for (unsigned item = 0; item < rowlen && val <= maxval; ++item) {
        printf("%u ", val++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you're so strongly promoting `for` over `do ... while`.  The OP's code is bad, yes, but the one or two loops he needs can be of any of the three available forms.

Comment: I suppose I was overzealous. Removing that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a single loop.

```
void print_tri(unsigned int max_val) {
    unsigned int row_lim = 1;
    unsigned int row_len = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= max_val; i++) {
        printf("%u ", i);
        if (++row_len == row_lim) {
            putchar('\n');
            row_lim++;
            row_len = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's clever — a tad complicated, but clever.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to practice the do while use this piece of code if you arent though go with @ShadowRanger's answer since i feel that it is better for this case scenario

```
int x,y,counter, row;
row = 1;
counter = 0;
y=10;
x=1;

do {
    do { 

    counter --;
    printf("%i ", x);
    x++;

    } while(counter > 0);
        printf("\n");
        row++;
        counter = row;

}   while (x<=y);
```

This adds 1 to the `row` variable each time the first do while loops to check in which row you're currently in then the `counter` is set to the row number that you're currently in to know how many numbers there will be in that row  the `x` variable is for the number that will be printed and the `y` variable is for how many numbers will be printed.

> Note: this code will finish any row that has missing numbers Example:
>   If you want to print 4 numbers this is what the code will print:
>   1
>   2 3
>   4 5 6
>   If you do NOT want this to happen change the first do while condition to
>   this: while(counter > 0 && x<=y);

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach the logic, all are fine. Here is was that specifies a `b` begin variable to control the spacing logic (none on the first, a single space before for the remainder in the row) and provides two format strings (`fmt1` and `fmt2`) to accommodate. The code increment a `c` - count of values to print per row until it reaches `n` - the number of counts per row.

Take a look at all answers and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    /* i, b - begin, c - count, n - num per row */
    int i, b = 1, c = 0, n = 1;
    char *fmt1 = "%d", *fmt2 = " %d";

    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printf (i == b ? fmt1 : fmt2, i);
        c++;
        if (c == n) {
            b = i + 1, c = 0, n++;
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/looppyrimid
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you.The answer i was looking for is the answer that Marcel Jacques Machado and Ivan posted.I am just a beginner.And the exercise was to practice nested loops. The other post were helpful as well.